# TCPDF. Is it possible to make the cell fillable after generating using TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

The number of rows depends on the user input.
I want to make the cell created, fillable or editable by the user.
Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated. THX.
    for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) {
    for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) {
    $w = 180/2;
    $h = 200/$row;

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell($w, $h, '', 1,0, 'C');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume by editable, you mean such that users may enter text into an area.

In that case you should look at the `TextField` method.
[TextField](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71d382a4356e7fb3f9fa72e53642c09c)

For a full example see example `014` in your examples folder or on the [tcpdf.org examples page](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)  The example includes setting form properties like fill and stroke color as well.

As noted in the example code, you will want to disable font sub-setting if you're including form fields in your output PDF.

Basically, just have your loop create the number of text fields you want.

Edit: The loop should give a unique field name to each `TextField`.

Comment: Hi thx for your quick response.
I did able to create the number of textfields, but the problem is whatever I type in textfield , all the textfield get all the same value. For example, i have 4 textfield, when I type "123" to the first textfield, all the textfield will have "123" as its value.

Here's  my codes:

    ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) { for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) { $w = 180/2; $h = 200/$row;
    
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->TextField('text1', $w, $h)

Comment: That's because you used the same name for each `TextField`, so instead of having them all called `'text1'` have them be called `'text' . $r.$c` or something of that nature.  It just needs to be unique per form field.  I've updated the answer to be more complete.

Comment: Thx man it works.. :) I'l just have to add borders to the textfields :)

Comment: Hi sir.. there's a problem again. The textfields are now ok.. but it seems it will only appear when I click it.. Is it possible to display the textfield border when it was called?

Comment: is it possible to just place these textfields inside the cell so it can have a borders? i mean so it would really look like a table?

Comment: If setting the border style/width in `setFormDefaultProp` (Seen in example 14) doesn't do what you want.  You'll have to draw the borders separately, like with `Rect` or drawing a series of `Line`s.

Comment: Hi I have another question, how can you remove the scroll bar in textfield? I notice that when the content is too long. the textfield produces scrollbar, how can I set to remove that? or set the maximum characters to be type in the textfield base on its height?